# Range Specification Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am reading two sources which seem to be giving me contradictory information on rules regarding range specification. [This](http://www.verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00039.htm) says that, "*Identical instance names cannot appear twice with other range specifications (even if ranges do not overlap each other)*" while [Intel's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJGvZSlsLKs)  tutorial on Verilog basics has an example of a 4-bit shifter at timestamp 34:28 with the following code:

```
integer i;

always@(inp,cnt)begin
  result[7:4] = 0;
  result[3:0] = inp;

  if(cnt==1)begin

    for(i=4; i<=7; i=i+1)begin
      result[i]=result[i-4];
    end

    result[3:0] = 0;

  end

end
```

Wouldn't "result[7:4]" and "result[3:0]" be an instance name that occurred twice with "other range specifications", one being [7:4] and the other being [3:0]? Or am I misunderstanding what is meant by "other range specifications"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Range Specification' refers to creating multiple module instances at once. E.g. this is invalid:

```
my_module m [3:0] (...);
my_module m [7:4] (...);
```

What you have in your example is called '[Part-select](http://www.verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00033.htm)'.